# symfony2 GET parameter overrides route parameter

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have an action which capable on several routes. I just defined the conflict part here.

```
/**
* @Route("/arama/ilanlar/{vehicleType}", requirements={"vehicleType"="(^$|araba|ticari-arac|motosiklet)"}, name="offer_search_fulltext_vehicletype")
* @Route("/{vehicleType}/{brand}", requirements={"vehicleType"="(araba|ticari-arac|motosiklet)", "brand"="[\w_-]+"}, name="offer_browse_vehicletype_brand")
* @Method({"GET"})
* @Template()
*/
public function searchAction(
    Request $request,
    $vehicleType = null,
    $brand = null,
) {
     ---
  }
```

for the first routing "brand" var may come as a GET parameter, but in twig path and url function passes this variable it still gets "brand" var as url parameter which I give null in action function definition.

I tried below line for setting route params but it didn't worked. How could I prevent this overriding ? I have to use same variable name on routing and get, if not it will break dynamism all over the code.

```
$request->attributes->set('_route_params', array_filter($request->get('_route_params')));
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The variables in the route definition (and passed to controller action method) is a request attribute hence it any data in the URL won't get automatically assigned to the variable in your action method.

You can use $request->get("some name") which looks up for the variable in the order of

URL params > Request Attributes > Post params

Comment: yeah $request->get("brand") gives me the value from get, but the problem is, generateUrl, twig.path, twig.url functions cannot handle it, if I send an array to path function with the current route. ex: {'brand' : 'bmw', 'brand1' : 'mercedes' } brand1 appear on the generated url but brand doesn't it because brand defined in the action as a route parameter and conflicts and it prefers the route params wheter is null or not.